# Sharing of class and object information across threads in TCL

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I would be happy if you could help me in the following problem:

Classes that are defined before the thread creation are not visible inside Thread. 
Is there a solution in tcl/iTCL to get the visibility of a class definition across threads?

Regards,
Sridhar S

Comment: Would you please post some code to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are no true globals in Tcl (except for a few things like the `env` array, which has special mutexes protecting it under the covers). All Tcl/itcl classes are *inherently* bound to a particular interpreter context, and every interpreter context is *inherently* bound to a particular thread. Tcl's implementation uses thread-specific data extensively to reduce the number of global locks to an absolute minimum; we even have non-locking memory allocators to make sure that that otherwise-global resource isn't a bottleneck. Tcl's “global” namespace is only actually global to a particular interpreter; other interpreters have their own “global” namespace and they're completely independent.

The thread extension sends messages between threads (well, strictly between the registered master interpreter in each thread). You can use it to simulate a global object by putting a proxy in the other threads that forwards method calls to the real master object in its home thread. This incurs quite a bit of overhead (and can cause deadlock if you've got too many proxies fighting back and forth) but is a simple way of doing things.

But you're better off designing your code to not have a need for single global master objects. They're *always* a bottleneck (unless they're entirely read-only, but in that case you can just duplicate them to each thread).